# Excel VBA / Refresh data from specific source without dialog

Tags: vba, excel

I have one sheet ("Sheet2") with imported data from TXT in my workbook.
Data are refreshed every day from file ZLX02S_FG_ & "sufix".
Name and path of the file are always known or calculated.

```
File name = ZLX02S_FG_20180821_095910.txt
Path name = C:\Users\lmisek\Desktop\WMS-L05-FG\
```

I have tried this code:

```
Sub Refresh_Macro()

    With Worksheets("Sheet2").QueryTables(1)
        .Connection = "TEXT;C:\Users\lmisek\Desktop\WMS-L05-FG\ZLX02S_FG_20180821_095910.txt"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
     End With

End Sub
```

Data on the sheet2 are refreshed, but only if one will choose file in the dialog.
I want to refresh them without dialog.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TextFilePromptOnRefresh](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.QueryTable.TextFilePromptOnRefresh) property is what you are looking for.

```
With Worksheets("Sheet2").QueryTables(1)
   .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
   .Connection = "TEXT;C:\Users\lmisek\Desktop\WMS-L05-FG\ZLX02S_FG_20180821_095910.txt"
   .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
End With
```

Please note, that it may also be necessary to explicitly set in code some of the import parameters, like delimiter etc.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thank you.