# Problem encountered while trying to remove select in query table refresh code

Tags: excel, vba

I have successfully connected to a text file as per given code by using Excel's Get & Transform (Power Query) experience to connect to Text files.
Next base text file is `Axis1.txt` which changes periodically.
Next I went to refresh the query table  with latest data.
I referred following references to learn about refreshing querytables

[How to reference and refresh a QueryTable in Excel 2016 in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39027286/how-to-reference-and-refresh-a-querytable-in-excel-2016-in-vba)

[Excel VBA / Refresh data from specific source without dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51982136/excel-vba-refresh-data-from-specific-source-without-dialog/51983783#51983783)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.querytable.refresh

**Now my Problem** .

Out of all referred methods I could get success in refreshing table with latest data when one of the query table cell is selected and the following command is given.

```
Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

Other types of code syntax refereed in various posts encounter an error mentioned against each line.

```
Sub reresh1()
'Sheet2.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

[image: errorl2]

```
  'Sheets("Sheet2").QueryTables.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

[image: errorl3]

```
  Selection.ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
   'WORKS FINE

   End Sub
```

Various other code syntax combinations were also tried but could not get success.

```
Sub TblImpV1()
' Macro1 Macro
    ActiveWorkbook.Queries.Add Name:="axis1", Formula:= _but 
        "let" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    Source = Csv.Document(File.Contents(""C:\mydirb\axis1.txt""),[Delimiter=""    "", Columns=11, Encoding=1252, QuoteStyle=QuoteStyle.None])," & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{""Column1"", Int64.Type}, {""Column2"", type date}, {""Column3"", type text}, {""Column4"", type text}, {""Column5"", type text}, {""Column6"", type number}, {""C" & _
        "olumn7"", type number}, {""Column8"", type text}, {""Column9"", type text}, {""Column10"", type text}, {""Column11"", type text}})" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "in" & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "    #""Changed Type"""
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects.Add(SourceType:=0, Source:= _
        "OLEDB;Provider=Microsoft.Mashup.OleDb.1;Data Source=$Workbook$;Location=axis1;Extended Properties=""""" _
        , Destination:=Range("$A$1")).QueryTable
        .CommandType = xlCmdSql
        .CommandText = Array("SELECT * FROM [axis1]")
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .PreserveColumnInfo = True
        .ListObject.DisplayName = "axis1"
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
    Range("B4").Select
End Sub
```

I Want to avoid Selection. Though procedure suggest that go to query table any cell and press refresh button.  I believe SO Experts posts on related matter must be right and I am doing something silly, due to my elementary knowledge of VBA Coding.
Any help or guidance in this matter is welcome. Would appreciate full related syntax instead of one liners.

**EDIT**

I could workout the solution to avoid the selection. Following code line works fine provided `B2` is a cell in the Query Table.

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").ListObject.QueryTable.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
```

However, If someone has a better solution , it is welcome.

Comment: you should also avoid `ActiveWorkbook` and use `ThisWorkbook` instead

Comment: @alowflyingpig  I use `ThisWorkbook` only, It is macro generated code which I have changed to point to `Thisworkbook ` in my actual code. It is not a problem area and has been shown only for reference.